# Android. NullReferenceException of Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development, so this is probably easy question.
There is Button defined in layout, but when Activity starting I see in debugger this Button is null. How this can happend?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/show_answer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_answer_button"/>
```

Activity:

```
        private Button mShowAnswer;
        mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
        mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                }
                else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you called `setContentView()` before the above code. Also, make sure you reference the correct layout file.

Comment: check your `TextView` is correctly initialized or not

Comment: @Shaishav, no, setContentView() certainly called after this.

Comment: @VishalThakkar, according his post he can compile and run the app, your idea does not correct.

Comment: @andrey.shedko, you must call `setContentView()` before any view binding in your activity

Comment: @saeedzhiany, yes, you're right, I can start app, but when launched activity with this button, it's throwing NRE.

Comment: Post the entire activity code with lifecycle methods if possible

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help. Yes, that's was about setContentView() in wrong place. @saeedzhiany, please add your comment as answer.

Comment: @andrey.shedko, I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240711/android-nullreferenceexception-of-button?noredirect=1#comment65818238_39240711) `setContentView()` method is in wrong place, it's must be place before binding button variable and button xml view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout_name);
private Button mShowAnswer;
mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 private Button mShowAnswer;

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                try {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

     mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
            mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                    }
                    else {
                        mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                    }
                }
            });

            }
```